# Is it possible to use JSDoc on CoffeeScript files without compiling them?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, documentation, jsdoc

I want to start formally documenting my NodeJS project written in CoffeeScript. After investigating most of the documentation options I've decided to (attempt to) go with JSDoc.

Given that I've installed this globally with NodeJS, is there any way I can get JSDoc to recognize my `.coffee` files the way Mocha and Node itself do? (Both support compiler flags, eliminating the need for build tools like Grunt or Gulp)

Answer (score 0):

Since JSDoc uses [espree](https://github.com/eslint/espree)(JavaScript AST parser), you can't do that. But some alternatives like [Codo](https://github.com/coffeedoc/codo) or [Docco](http://jashkenas.github.io/docco/) exist.